# Recursively Iterate over Hashtable (Powershell)

Tags: powershell, adjacency-matrix, connected-components

I have a hashtable that mimics this table. So for example $h['C'].C maps to 3, $h['A'].A maps to 1

| Groups | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 5 | 2 | 0 |
| C | 0 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| D | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |

I would like to iterate over the table to find the groupings.
For example the output would be:
A
B,C
D

A and D are on their own line since there is only one entry without a zero in either the column or row.
B and C are together since their column and/or row intersect with a number greater than zero.
I think the solution should involve some type of recursion.

I have this, but I think I need to recursively call it

```
foreach($i in $h.GetEnumerator()){
   $Results = 'Groups'
   foreach($t in $h.GetEnumerator()){
            $iString = $i.Name
            $tString = $t.Name
            if($h[$iString].$tString -ne '0'){
               if($iString -eq $tString){
                    $Results += ','+$tString 
               }
               else{
                #recursive call
               }
            }
   }
   $Results
}
```

Comment: Show us your coding attempt at solving this problem. You might also want to consider start accepting answers to your previous questions.

Comment: Is the table always reflected down the diagonal? That is, does [X,Y] always equal [Y,X]? It is that just a coincidence in your sample data?

Comment: Yes, it is reflected down the diagonal.

Comment: I think you can convert this to a graph problem if you treat your hashtable as an Adjacency Matrix (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) where a non-zero value indicates an edge connecting two nodes in an undirected graph. You're then trying to find all the Connected Components - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory) - which are the sets of nodes in each distinct subgraph.

Comment: yes, essentially this is an adjacency matrix where I need to find the connected components

Answer (score 1):

Per comments, you can convert this to a graph problem if you treat your hashtable as an [Adjacency Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) where a non-zero value indicates an edge connecting two nodes in a directed graph.

You're then trying to find all the [Connected Components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)) - which are the sets of nodes in each distinct subgraph.

You can turn your hashtable into a list of edges in a directed graph like this:

```
$data = [ordered] @{
    "A" = [ordered] @{
        "A" = 1
        "B" = 0
        "C" = 0
        "D" = 0
    }
    "B" = [ordered] @{
        "A" = 0
        "B" = 5
        "C" = 2
        "D" = 0
    }
    "C" = [ordered] @{
        "A" = 0
        "B" = 2
        "C" = 3
        "D" = 0
    }
    "D" = [ordered] @{
        "A" = 0
        "B" = 0
        "C" = 0
        "D" = 2
    }
}

$nodes = $data.GetEnumerator() | foreach-object { $_.Key };
$edges = $data.GetEnumerator() | foreach-object {
    $start = $_.Key;
    $_.Value.GetEnumerator() | foreach-object {
        if( $_.Value -ne 0 )
        {
            write-output (new-object PSCustomObject -Property ([ordered] @{
                "Start" = $start
                "End"   = $_.Key
            }));
        }
    }
};

write-host ($nodes | format-list * | out-string);
# A
# B
# C
# D

write-host ($edges | format-table | out-string);
# Start End
# ----- ---
# A     A
# B     B
# B     C
# C     B
# C     C
# D     D
```

Then you "just" need to do a bunch of [Depth-First Searches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Pseudocode) to find the subgraphs...

```
# based on the non-recursive pseudocode at
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Pseudocode

$subgraphs = new-object System.Collections.ArrayList;

$unvisited = new-object System.Collections.ArrayList;
$unvisited.AddRange($nodes);

while( $unvisited.Count -gt 0 )
{

    $subgraph = @();
    $node     = $unvisited[0];

    # let S be a stack
    $stack = new-object System.Collections.Generic.Stack[string];

    # S.push(v)
    $stack.Push($node);

    # while S is not empty do
    while( $stack.Count -gt 0 )
    {

        # v = S.pop()
        $node = $stack.Pop();

        # if v is not labeled as discovered then
        if( $unvisited -contains $node )
        {

            # label v as discovered
            $unvisited.Remove($node);

            # for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
            $adjacents = $edges | where-object { $_.Start -eq $node };
            foreach( $adjacent in $adjacents )
            {
                # S.push(w)
                $stack.Push($adjacent.End);
            }

            $subgraph += $node;

        }
    }

    $null = $subgraphs.Add($subgraph);

}
```

which gives these results:

```
foreach( $subgraph in $subgraphs )
{
    write-host $subgraph
}
# A
# B C
# D
```

Note - not tested for any datasets other than the one in the question!